# MOLEX to Micro-USB to power Pi

Tags: power, power-supply

I am thinking about modding some sort of system where it would be necessary to connect a MOLEX (Internal PSU connection) to a Micro-USB 5V (VCC) connection.

### Molex Pinout

[image: Molex Pinout]

### Micro-USB Pinout

[image: Micro-USB Pinout]

Now, since I'm not fully aware of the steps, is it necessary to set up a NPN BJT transistor connection to run it through? Could I instead just connect the 5V molex connection straight to the 5V Micro-USB connection in-line, or will that fry the Pi?

Comment: 5V is 5V.  I would not hesitate for an instant.  Personally I'd power via the more accessible expansion header pins but be aware that does bypass the polyfuse.

Comment: I am aware that it bypasses the polyfuse, but do I need to run it through the transistor as mentioned above between the PSU and the RPi?

Comment: I came by looking for a pinout for a micro-usb. Be warned: the above image is the FEMALE pinout, but OP's pic shows the MALE connector for molex. I don't care if people call that molex connector "female" as you stick that plug into things. If you were converting a normal PSU molex to micro USB male and followed the above images, you'd having your vcc and ground backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect directly.

You'd use a transistor only if the current used by the Pi was greater than the current supplied by the device that the Molex cable is connected to, or if you were using a different supply voltage. In either case, you would need a different supply as well as the 5v supply.

In other words: if whatever is attached to the Molex end provides at least 1 amp at 5 volts, you should be able to run a Pi. If it provides 2.5 amps at 5 volts, you will be able to run a Pi 2 with all USB ports.

The official power requirements can be found here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs